# How can I place code in a function using macros?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a function

```cpp
void foo()
{
    foo1();
}
```

I want to have a macro that I can use in other place like that:

```
ADD_FUNCTION_TO_FOO(foo2());
```

So the function foo() will look like that for the compiler:

```cpp
void foo()
{
    foo1();
    foo2();
}
```

Is that possible to achieve? Or perhaps is there other way around that?

Comment: No, that is impossible.

Comment: I mean, your can write `foo` in the first place to take a lambda argument which defaults to no-op, or something similar. But you can't re-open a function and change it later.

Comment: Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: You should really update `foo` function to do whatever you want it to do. If this is not possible, then you should clearly explain your problem, your expectation and why you cannot use the obvious solution which is **(1)** to fix incomplete function `foo` or **(2)** defining a function `foo_new` that does what you want and call that function instead. 

You already assume that your solution is the good one instead of explaining clearly what you want to achieve so that we could give you appropriate solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify a function. The definition of `foo()` is exactly what it does, forever.

But you could write `foo` to be extensible in the first place:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::function<void()>> extra_callbacks_for_foo;

void foo1();

void foo()
{
    foo1();
    for (auto& cb : extra_callbacks_for_foo)
        cb();
}

#define ADD_FUNCTION_TO_FOO(expr) \
  (extra_callbacks_for_foo.push_back([&]() { (expr); }))
```

See the [working example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/610e0b9909bbd599).